# Is there a way to get a GUI representation of Mini Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I'm learning about Meteor at the moment.  Really impressed with the vision of the framework.  Meteor retains data on the client side with "Mini Mongo" (http://www.quora.com/Meteor-web-framework/How-does-Meteors-Minimongo-work) - an in browser version of Mongo DB.  I've connected Robomongo to the server side DB to surf it with a GUI, and I was wondering if there was a way to get a GUI representation of Mini Mongo.  A Chrome dev tools hack perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a meteorite package developed in one of the summer [hackathons](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/07/10/congratulations-to-the-meteor-summer-hackathon-2013-teams).

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/z-mongo-admin
https://github.com/gterrono/meteor-admin-ui

It is in a very raw state, but should be enough if you are just using it for learning.