# Where are the (local) Meteor Collection stored?

Tags: meteor

I have (local) Meteor collection .

```
ErrorsCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

To this Collection I am adding the error messages. I would like to know where does this local meteor collection getting stored ?
I am connected to meteor mongo via Robomongo , I am unable to find the ErrorCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In memory ([minimongo](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases)). From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection):

> If you pass null as the name, then you're creating a local collection. It's not synchronized anywhere; it's just a local scratchpad that supports Mongo-style find, insert, update, and remove operations. (On both the client and the server, this scratchpad is implemented using Minimongo.)

My understanding is that robomongo only talks to normal mongodb instances. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779159/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-gui-representation-of-mini-mongo).

One way to see a table of data in minimongo is to use `console.table` like this:

```js
console.table(ErrorsCollection.find().fetch());
```

Comment: Is there a way to see what is stored on minimongo ?

Comment: I just updated the answer - you can use `console.table`.